# How to create a dictionary by a list of lists inside a for loop

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, nested

Good Morning,

I am trying to create a dictionary where:

I have a list of lists: [[string, string, string], [...] ...]] [] [...]]] [] [...] i would like to each list become a nested dict, However, my code only generates the dictionary for the last item in the list, why does it happen?

#### code:

```
keys = ['tf-idf', 'pres']
    lista_dic = []
    for item in regularizado:
        dic = {name: {key: 0 for key in keys} for name in item}
        lista_dic.append(dic.copy())
    dic
```

### output:

```
    {'horas': {'tf-idf': 0, 'pres': 0},
    'banco': {'tf-idf': 0, 'pres': 0},
     'controle': {'tf-idf': 0, 'pres': 0},
     'empregada': {'tf-idf': 0, 'pres': 0},
     'calcular': {'tf-idf': 0, 'pres': 0},
     'domestica': {'tf-idf': 0, 'pres': 0},
     'salario': {'tf-idf': 0, 'pres': 0}}
```

### list of lists:

```
    [['trabalho', 'jornada', 'horas', 'semanal', 'clt'],
     ['intrajornada', 'intervalo', 'reforma', 'trabalhista', 'clt'],
     ['desconto',
      'salario',
      'empregado',
      'domestico',
      'calcular',
      'descontar',
      'inss'],
     ['maternidade',
      'licenca',
      'estabilidade',
      'domestica',
      'empregada',
      '2018',
      'apos'],
     ['aviso', 'previo', 'previo', 'indenizado', 'dias', 'trabalhado'],
     ['calcular', 'rescisao', 'passo', 'contrato'],
     ['afastamento', 'trabalho', 'empregada', 'doenca', 'domestica'],
     ['feriado', 'empregada', 'direito', 'domestica', 'empregado'],
     ['fgts',
      '2018',
      'porque',
      'liberado',
      'onde',
      'inativo',
      'sacar',
      'ser',
      'x',
      'guia',
      'como',
      'por',
      'dezembro',
      '13o',
      'decimo',
      'terceiro',
      'novembro',
      'diferente'],
     ['como', 'registrar', 'empregada', 'empregado', 'carteira', 'faco'],
     ['dias',
      'ferias',
      'empregada',
      'direito',
      'trabalha',
      'quantos',
      'minha',
      'semana'],
     ['carteira', 'trabalho', 'como', 'ferias', 'ferias', 'aumento'],
     ['carteira', 'trabalho', 'como', 'ferias', 'ferias', 'aumento'],
     ['empregado',
      'ferias',
      'ferias',
      'domestico',
      'empregada',
      'dias',
      'trabalha',
      'domestico',
      'direito'],
     ['como', 'saber', 'inss', 'saldo', 'fgts', 'empregda', 'quanto'],
     ['trabalho',
      'jornada',
      'jornadas',
      'quais',
      '12x36',
      'sao',
      'almoco',
      'como',
      'o',
      'tempo',
      'empregado',
      'folga',
      'faz',
      'feriado'],
     ['guia', 'esocial', 'faco', 'valor'],
     ['banco', 'horas', 'como', 'domestica', 'empregada'],
     ['como',
      'trabalha',
      'calculo',
      'salario',
      'periodo',
      'noturno',
      'cuidador',
      'noite',
      'empregado'],
     ['empregada', 'licenca', 'maternidade', 'posso', 'assim', 'embora'],
     ['empregada',
      'domestica',
      'trabalhar',
      'domestica',
      'carga',
      'horas',
      'jornada',
      'dia',
      'pode'],
     ['cuidadora',
      'tenho',
      'trabalha',
      'jornada',
      'hora',
      'extra',
      '24x48',
      '24',
      'folga',
      'quantos',
      'dias',
      'deve',
      'faz',
      '24h',
      '24/24',
      'adicional',
      'noturno'],
     ['trabalha',
      'empregado',
      'dia',
      'salario',
      'se',
      'como',
      'faco',
      'calcular',
      'empregada',
      'horas'],
     ['pagar',
      'gostaria',
      'saber',
      'quanto',
      'devo',
      'assistente',
      'pessoal',
      'quanto',
      'posso',
      'empregado'],
     ['valor',
      'qual',
      'gratuidade',
      'gratis',
      '30',
      'dias',
      'pagar',
      'periodo',
      'pago',
      'ser',
      'paga',
      'quanto',
      'primeiro',
      'depois',
      'mes',
      'apos',
      'mensalidade',
      'saber',
      'gostaria',
      'gratis'],
     ['contrato', 'experiencia', 'funciona', 'experiencia', 'ser'],
     ['empregada',
      'licenca',
      'posso',
      'assim',
      'embora',
      'despedir',
      'retorna',
      'volta'],
     ['trabalhar',
      'menos',
      'horas',
      'dias',
      'empregada',
      'pode',
      'tempo',
      'pode',
      'dia'],
     ['como',
      'empregada',
      'guia',
      'fgts',
      'encargos',
      'empregado',
      'inss',
      'gero'],
     ['entendi',
      'texto',
      'nada',
      'nao',
      'eu',
      'li',
      'o',
      'li',
      'continuo',
      'e',
      'entender',
      'explicar',
      'melhor',
      'duvida'],
     ['o',
      'salario',
      'liquido',
      'valor',
      'r',
      'minimo',
      'liquido',
      'bruto',
      'esse',
      '1.108,38',
      'empregada',
      'domestica',
      'paulo',
      'sao',
      'minimo',
      'salario',
      'bruto'],
     ['afastamento',
      'inss',
      'periodo',
      'prorrogar',
      'precisa',
      'minha',
      'empregada',
      'estender',
      'inss'],
     ['guias',
      'esocial',
      'atrasadas',
      'voces',
      'tenho',
      'regularizam',
      'atualizam'],
     ['esocial',
      'social',
      'youtube',
      'empresas',
      'web',
      'onde',
      'zenaide',
      '2018'],
     ['guias',
      'esocial',
      'atrasadas',
      'voces',
      'tenho',
      'regularizam',
      'atualizam'],
     ['rescisao',
      'contrato',
      'empregada',
      'domestica',
      'domestica',
      'indireta',
      'rescindir',
      'trabalho',
      'calcular',
      'rescisao',
      'calculo',
      'justa',
      'causa',
      'trabalhista'],
     ['afastamento',
      'inss',
      'empregado',
      'aposentadoria',
      'domestica',
      'empregada',
      'trabalho',
      'doenca',
      'licenca'],
     ['aviso', 'previo', 'previo', 'indenizado', 'trabalhado', 'dias'],
     ['horas', 'banco', 'trabalhista', 'reforma'],
     ['calculo', 'ferias', 'ferias', 'calculo', 'salario'],
     ['cbo',
      'que',
      'devo',
      'utilizar',
      'qual',
      'cargo',
      'carteira',
      'trabalho',
      'ctps',
      'correto',
      'empregada',
      'domestica',
      'baba'],
     ['contrato', 'experiencia', 'experiencia', 'rescisao'],
     ['desconto', 'salario', 'salario', 'inss'],
     ['cadastro', 'esocial', 'social', 'cadastrar'],
     ['empregada', 'licenca', 'maternidade', 'domestica'],
     ['aviso', 'ferias', 'ferias', 'valor', 'outlook'],
     ['compensar', 'faltas', 'horas', 'extras', 'atrasos'],
     ['certificado',
      'digital',
      'codigo',
      'acesso',
      'esocial',
      'cadastro',
      'posso',
      'se',
      'acessar'],
     ['como', 'preencher', 'carteira', 'trabalho', 'jeito', 'certo'],
     ['preencher', 'carteira', 'trabalho', 'como', 'rescisao'],
     ['ferias',
      'antes',
      'empregada',
      'dar',
      'posso',
      'pode',
      'ano',
      'antecipar',
      'empregado',
      '1'],
     ['empregada',
      'trabalhar',
      'jornada',
      'cuidadora',
      'posso',
      'contratar',
      'pode',
      '24x24',
      '24x48',
      '48x48',
      'gravida',
      'o',
      'se',
      'como',
      'funciona',
      'plantao',
      'empregado',
      'fazer',
      'quanto',
      'devo',
      'pagar',
      'possivel'],
     ['empregada',
      'trabalhar',
      'a',
      'deve',
      'dias',
      'segunda',
      'sabado',
      'sabados',
      'vou',
      'receber',
      'rescisao',
      'quanto'],
     ['empregada',
      'trabalhar',
      'emprego',
      'estou',
      'contratar',
      'procurando',
      'domestica',
      'quero',
      'preciso',
      'empregado'],
     ['contratar',
      'cuidadora',
      'preciso',
      'empregada',
      'estou',
      'cuidador',
      'domestica'],
     ['o',
      'sistema',
      'voces',
      'guia',
      'emitem',
      'calcula',
      'como',
      'funciona',
      'esocial',
      'pagamento',
      'ponto'],
     ['sistema', 'funciona', 'como', 'o', 'faz', 'esse'],
     ['banco', 'horas', 'funciona'],
     ['calcular', 'terceiro', 'decimo', 'decimo', 'empregada', 'salario'],
     ['como', 'preencher', 'contrato', 'experiencia', 'carteira', 'trabalho'],
     ['falta', 'desconto', 'calculo', 'calcular'],
     ['empregado',
      'tenho',
      'ficar',
      'retorno',
      'afastamento',
      'aposentadoria',
      'demiti-lo',
      'posso',
      'volta',
      'depois',
      'cessada',
      'sido',
      'ter',
      'invalidez',
      'trabalho',
      'beneficio',
      'apos',
      'domestica',
      'empregada',
      'aceitar',
      'obrigacao',
      'empregadora',
      'saber',
      'gostaria',
      'licenca'],
     ['periodo',
      'experiencia',
      'esocial',
      'preciso',
      'colocar',
      'como',
      'informar'],
     ['respostas',
      'pagar',
      'consulta',
      'eu',
      'pago',
      'pra',
      'quanto',
      'tirar',
      'duvidas',
      'tenho',
      'custo',
      'alguma',
      'coisa'],
     ['horas',
      'trabalho',
      'almoco',
      '8',
      'intervalo',
      'descanco',
      'o',
      'diarias',
      'incluso',
      'as',
      'incluem'],
     ['direito', 'empregada', 'pis', 'pis', 'domestica', 'domestica', 'saber'],
     ['noturno', 'adicional', 'calculo', 'horas', 'calcular'],
     ['salario', 'empregado', 'empregada', 'domestico', 'domestica', 'salario'],
     ['hora', 'extra', 'noturna'],
     ['pagar', 'boleto', 'cartao', 'nao', 'credito'],
     ['ana', 'bem', 'boa', 'ola', 'noite', 'como', 'vai', 'tudo', 'tudo'],
     ['quanto', 'salario', 'empregada', 'pagar', 'devo', 'domestica'],
     ['carteira', 'trabalho', 'preencher'],
     ['cadastro',
      'fazer',
      'como',
      'esocial',
      'social',
      'acesso',
      'faco',
      'esocial',
      'codigo',
      'pessoa',
      'fez',
      'declaracao'],
     ['duvida',
      'duvidas',
      'algumas',
      'ajudar',
      'confusa',
      'tirar',
      'estou',
      'pode',
      'ajuda',
      'pode',
      'fazer',
      'to',
      'preciso',
      'me',
      'tenho',
      'quero',
      'coisa'],
     ['sistema', 'como', 'quero', 'servico', 'usar', 'contratar', 'cadastrar'],
     ['licenca', 'maternidade', 'ferias', 'ferias', 'apos'],
     ['cuidadores', 'escala', 'montar', 'como', 'trabalho', 'que'],
     [],
     ['empregada',
      'domestica',
      'a',
      'pode',
      'baba',
      'fazer',
      'servico',
      'funcoes',
      'cuidadora',
      'executar',
      'outras',
      'o',
      'acontece',
      'trabalha'],
     ['horas',
      'banco',
      'controle',
      'empregada',
      'calcular',
      'domestica',
      'salario']]
```

Comment: You're looking at the wrong thing for output? You created a list of dicts in `lista_dic`, are you looking at `dic` at the end?

Comment: man, you solved the problem i've been trying to figure it out for a while hahaha

Comment: hehe, it happens. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think your code is working fine... You are just inspecting the wrong variable.

Try

```py
keys = ['tf-idf', 'pres']
lista_dic = []
for item in regularizado:
    dic = {name: {key: 0 for key in keys} for name in item}
    lista_dic.append(dic.copy())
lista_dic
```

Or simpler:

```py
keys = ['tf-idf', 'pres']
lista_dic = []
for item in regularizado:
    lista_dic.append({name: {key: 0 for key in keys} for name in item})
lista_dic
```